# Visual Studio Code JSON object losing intellisense in new function

Tags: javascript, json, configuration, visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense

```
function first_function() {
  var json = { a: 0, b: 1 };
  second_function(json);
}

function second_function(json) {
  // Pressing ctrl+enter to start intellisense
  json.[ctrl+enter] // No intellisense, properties a and b won't show
}
```

Hey so I'm noticing this weird thing with Visual Studio Code where I have a JavaScript function, like **first_function** in my example where a variable that is a JSON is created and passed into **second_function**.

**The problem**: When in the second function, when I try to start intellisense for the JSON, I'm not getting the properties **a and b** to show up. What is happening and is there something that can fix that? Do I have a poorly configured VSC or what?

Comment: Other things besides the `json` from `second_function` could be passed in; Intellisense is a best-guess, but it's not running the code from your file to try and guess what you might do in the future.

Comment: just because you name a variable the same name(json) as function argument(json) it doesn't mean VSCode can deduce the type of the function argument. Try and use js-doc in your code to hint types https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JsDoc-support-in-JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> just because you name a variable the same name(json) as function argument(json) it doesn't mean VSCode can deduce the type of the function argument. Try and use js-doc in your code to hint types https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JsDoc-support-in-JavaScript  -  mpm

This answer works thank you so much! The solution is impractical and wordy though. This is a project in Google Apps Script (GAS) with ECMAScript 5 (ES5) and using Visual Studio Code for editing and type checking.

The way to make this work was doing like this...

```
/**
 * This long note to get intellisense for an object
 * @param {Object} json
 * @param {Number} json.a
 * @param {Number} json.b
 */
function second_function(json) {
  json.[Start Intellisense] //A AND B ARE THERE YAY
}
```

As a solution because Google Apps Script is so stupid, I've ended up making var constructors out of the objects I needed. GAS cannot necessarily make a class and because using a `var json = {}` then making a very long JSDoc for it just didn't feel worth the effort.

This was more practical

```
/**
 * Sets up the record I want to build
 * @param {Array} input
 */
function Json2Construct(input) {
  /** @type Number */
  this.a = input[0];
  /** @type Number */
  this.b = input[1];
};

/**
 * Creates the record and sends to next function
 */
function first_function() {
  var input = [0, 1];
  var json = new Json2Construct(input);
  second_function(json);
}

/**
 * Will have intellisense this time too
 * @param {Json2Construct} json
 */
function second_function(json) {
  json.[Start Intellisense] // Woo a and b are also there!
}
```

I really appreciate the help, thank you so much!